# Как перенести текст на графике plotly, python?

Tags: python, текст, graph, plotly

Код, с которым я строю график:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = go.Figure(data = go.Scatter(x = result.x,
                                 y = result.y, 
                                 mode = 'markers',
                                 marker_color = result['tp'],
                                 text = result['text'],
                                 marker=dict(
        colorscale='Viridis')))
fig.update_layout(autosize=False,
                 width = 800,
                 height = 800)
fig.show()
```

Текст при наведении на точку графика обрезается:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пробовал добавлять в текст '\n' но текст все равно не переносился
Подскажите, как исправить?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64547157/15035314